# Edittext starting point problem Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my code,am having EdiText and its code is:

```
<EditText 
  android:layout_height="150dp" 
  android:id="@+id/profiledescription"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"

  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:paddingLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:enabled="false"



  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"></EditText>
```

But the problem is cursor is starting from middle rather than usual first position:

[image: Editext cursor]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll probably need to set `android:gravity="top"` for the corresponding XML-element in the layout.

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying the following in your EditText XML declaration:

```
<EditText android:gravity="left|top" ... />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `android:gravity="top"` to the layout for that `EditText`.

```
<EditText 
  android:layout_height="150dp" 
  android:id="@+id/profiledescription"
  android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
  android:gravity="top"
  android:textSize="16sp"
  android:paddingLeft="20dp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:enabled="false"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
android:gravity="top" android:singleLine="false"
```